# How to overlay a video into other video as blackground at specific time in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

MY CODE

`-i "A.mov" -i "B.mp4"  -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[a];[1:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):eof_action=pass,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy "f.mov" -y`

This will overlay B.mp4 in font of A.mov but I need B.mp4 As blackground
Thank You.

[image: LAYER]

Comment: What's the background for the first 5 seconds supposed to be?

Comment: Main video[a.mov] will have Transparent Box in a center.Second video is content behind first one.